# Height of floating divs are zero at first time, but ok at second time

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a `jQuery mobile` site, and I want to show three floating divs.

Because I do not know the content of the divs, I do not know the heights of them, but I want to make them to be equal height.

I thought, this is so simple with the following code:

```
var maxHeight = 0;
var columns = $('.column');
console.log(columns);
$.each(columns, function (idx, obj) {
    console.log('Outter: ' + $(obj).outerHeight() + "\nInner: " + $(obj).innerHeight() + '\nRegular: ' + $(obj).height() + "\n-----------------\n") ;
    if ($(obj).outerHeight() > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = $(obj).outerHeight();
    }
});
console.log(maxHeight);
$.each(columns, function (idx, obj) {
    $(obj).outerHeight(maxHeight);
});
```

But there are always surprises in the `jQuery mobile` world.

When I first download the page, the divs are just showing the height of padding, and there are very strange thing in the console.

After a page refresh, everything is normal, and works as I expected.

If it's not enough, Firefox and Chrom shows different values after the page refresh. In the first div, there is an image.

The output of the first page load both in chrome and firefox (the second section is happening twice):

```
Outter: 0
Inner: 0
Regular: 0
-----------------
 jquery.min.js line 2 > eval:19:1
Outter: 0
Inner: 0
Regular: -20
-----------------
 jquery.min.js line 2 > eval:19:1
0
```

Second time, after the page refresh

```
Outter: 342
Inner: 342
Regular: 342
-----------------
 14g100312503-webkamera_kabelell-h5683.html:284:1
Outter: 112
Inner: 112
Regular: 92
-----------------
 14g100312503-webkamera_kabelell-h5683.html:284:1
Outter: 275
Inner: 275
Regular: 255
-----------------
 14g100312503-webkamera_kabelell-h5683.html:284:1
342
```

And chrome is showing 16 for the first div.

Can anybody explain me, why is this happens?

Unfortunately I can not show you the live example. Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7w86dL1s/3/) link, but in fiddle, it works.

**EDIT** I forgot to mentioned, this is an inline javascript in a file, where the divs are, not from a `.js` file. And since, it write it to the console, I am sure, it is running.

And what is strage also, (I realized this when I wrote this post), the first time, the caller is `jquery.min.js line 2 > eval:19:1` and the second time `14g100312503-webkamera_kabelell-h5683.html:284:1`

Comment: You didn't provide enough context in question to make your issue clearer. How do you call this snippet code? That's said, sounds like you just need to wrap it inside window onload handler

Comment: @A.Wolff This is an inline javascript and I am running it on document ready.

Comment: So try instead window onload event and see if that makes any difference

Comment: window.onload, and document.ready are not solutions, because jQuery.mobile is loading from ajax, so these events not happens. I've tried, `$(document).on('pagecreate', function () {` and for some reasons it runs the snippet 3 times, but the result are the same.

Comment: No, not the same. If I am running it from `pagecreate` it runs a several times, but heights are always 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile, to get heights you should run your code in the pageshow event of the specific page that includes the columns:

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#page1", function(){ 
    var maxHeight = 0;
    var columns = $('.column');
    $.each(columns, function (idx, obj) {
        console.log('Outter: ' + $(obj).outerHeight() + "\nInner: " + $(obj).innerHeight() + '\nRegular: ' + $(obj).height() + "\n-----------------\n") ;
        if ($(obj).outerHeight() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(obj).outerHeight();
        }
    });
    console.log(maxHeight);
    $.each(columns, function (idx, obj) {
        $(obj).outerHeight(maxHeight);
    });

});
```

or using the pagecontainer widget

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function (event, ui) {
    if (ui.toPage.prop("id") == "page1") {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        ...
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7w86dL1s/5/)**

Comment: This was exactly what I need. The solution was the `pagecontainershow`. Thank you very much, to read through my long post, and giving me the solution. +1 and accepted.